# Iframe memory leak

Tags: vb.net, pdf, iframe, label

I have an iframe that displays a page. The underlying page does a redirect to a pdf that I got from the database. The iframe is actually the text of a label control. It seems to happen randomly that the memory usage will go up when looking at images. This doesn't happen every time that an image is loaded in IE. I can't seem to figure out what is happening. Here is the code for the text of the label that displays the pdf.

```
strReturn &= "<iframe name=""pdffrname"" width=""100%"" height=""100%"" src=""dataframe.aspx?" & Request.QueryString.ToString & "&topage=" & cboToPage.SelectedValue & """/>"
```

Is there anything I need to do to the iframe so that the memory usage stops spiking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Memory Leaks in IE8 (and IE9 and IE10)](http://com.hemiola.com/2009/11/23/memory-leaks-in-ie8/) by Jens-Ingo Farley suggests that there's nothing you can really do about it except for reload the entire page:

> The user hitting F5 occasionally (if the page can handle it) will
>   unload window.top and free its memory, but there is no apparent
>   programmatic workaround. If the page is in an iframe, unloading the
>   iframe has no effect. It seems that window.top must be unloaded.

Comment: That link was helpful. Gotta love IE. Thanks